# Testing the similarity of datasets containing many variables to asses model predictive performance

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, model-evaluation

I have 2 large datasets containing many variables, A & B, where A is taken from period t and B is taken from period t + n. I have a model that was trained on dataset A whose predictive performance has now deteriorated on dataset B.

I want to test the similarity of the 2 datasets in order to assess whether the decrease in performance of the model is due to;

1. A statistically significant change in the underlying
   data, i.e., there is a fundamental change in the data-
   generating process and dataset A no longer contains
   predictive information for the behaviour
2. The deterioration is due to overfitting

Firstly, are points 1 & 2 essentially the same thing?

If not, what are some methods to investigate this? I would be interested in hearing if there is a bayesian approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think these cases are both the same, if the data set has changed, then due to over-fitting on the previous situation, the model performance deteriorates.

I guess you could ask yourself if the deterioration is statistically significant. This is a statistical test depending on how many samples you've calculated your accuracy for and how large the deviation is.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to work out is whether there has been a material change in the data-generating process. I.e., does dataset A no longer contain valid information on the behavior of the process or whether dataset B simply carries some variation that the model cannot handle due to overfitting. Does this make sense?

Comment: Definetely makes sense, and I think the question is then, "Is the deterioration significant?". So if you have 100 samples in the test set (A and B), and accuracy drops from 90 to 80%, then yes, significant, if you have only 10 samples, same drop would not be significant.